Google Fit Sdk throws error 403: access denied while log in
While users are trying to connect the app with Google fit API, they are getting a popup in which says:

Access blocked: app has not completed the Google Verification process
Error 403: access_denied.

I have checked App Content tab and from there everything is completed in Need Attention tab.
On google cloud, in OAuth consent screen, publish status is in Testing. Shall I publish app from here or not? Looking for guidance.

t seems like your app is encountering an error related to Google's OAuth consent screen configuration. Here are some steps you can take to resolve the issue:
Review OAuth Consent Screen Configuration:
Make sure that you have provided all the required information on the OAuth consent screen, including the app name, user support email, developer contact information, and privacy policy URL. Ensure that your app's logo and other details are correctly configured.
Check if you have filled out all the necessary fields under the "Scopes for Google APIs" section. Ensure that you have selected the scopes required for your application to access Google Fit API.
Verification Status:
Ensure that your app has been verified by Google. You can check the status of your verification process in the Google Cloud Console under the OAuth consent screen section. If it's still in testing, you might encounter issues when users try to connect.
Publishing the App:
If your app is ready for production use and has completed the verification process, you can consider publishing it from the OAuth consent screen settings in the Google Cloud Console. Publishing your app will make it available for general users, and it should resolve the "Access blocked" error.
However, if your app is not ready for production use or if you are still testing, it's better to keep it in the testing phase until you are fully confident about its functionality and compliance with Google's policies.
Review Error Logs:
Check the error logs or console output for more detailed information about the "Access blocked" error. It might provide additional clues about what went wrong during the authentication process.
Contact Google Support:
If you are unable to resolve the issue with the above steps, consider reaching out to Google Cloud Support for further assistance. They can help you troubleshoot the problem and provide guidance on resolving the OAuth consent screen issues.
